# Trimming the directory containing a file to just parent folder in Vim

Tags: vim

If the path to my file is `~/exampleJsApp/js/test.js` I would like vim to print out `js/test.js`. I have looked at the [vim wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Get_the_name_of_the_current_file) but `:echo expand('%:p:h')` gets the whole path (just head) (`/usr/username/exampleJsApp/js/test`).

How do I trim out most of the folders and only show the direct parent?

Answer (score 1):

> How do I trim out most of the folders and only show the direct parent?

Expand the parent directory and the file separately, and then join them:

```
:echo expand('%:p:h:t').'/'.expand('%:t')
```

Answer (score 0):

Why did you look at the Vim Wiki instead of Vim's built-in documentation?

```
:help file<C-d>
```

returns too many results but

```
:help filename<C-d>
```

only returns a few, including the very promising

```
:help filename-modifiers
```

which incidentally happens to contain the answer to your question.

Comment: While I agree with your answer, the goal of SO is to become a "repository of answer", so a good answer should contain the information, plus eventually how to get it.

Comment: I don't care at all about SO and its goals. Learning how to fish is vastly more useful than being handed a fish.